# Twitter account/verify_credentials returning 34 error code

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I found a whole bunch of related questions here, but since Twitter had made a lot of changes in its API, most of them are outdated (+ nothing actually solved my problem).

So My website is a semi social network (with posts, likes comments etc). The user has the option to post to twitter and facebook through my site. Everything is working just fine, posts are finding their way to both FB and TW.

I'm using [Twitter oauth php library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth), posting is done like so:

```
$response = $connection->post("statuses/update", array('status' => "Tweet"));
```

but when if I want to verify user's credentials like so:

```
$response = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials.json");
```

I get:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [message] => Sorry, that page does not exist
                [code] => 34
            )
```

I don't think the problem is in the authentication process nor in the app settings, for I was able to post a tweet but got that same error, both using the same access token (and obviously the same app).

apparently you get this 34 error for a variety of cases, the documentations is so ambiguous about it.
So any troubleshooting techniques are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
$response = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");  // Remove the .json
```